# Detect if a iOS permission dialog is showing

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to determine if a permission prompt is showing on iOS?

In my game, I want to stop many things when the app goes to background, but I don't want to stop them when the permission prompt shows (specifically record video permission shown by ReplayKit). So I want to know why the app goes to background: because home button is pressed, or because permission prompt is shown.